# Make executable jar with JavaFx plugin for gradle

Tags: javafx, gradle, executable-jar, netbeans-7.3

I'm trying to make an executable jar.
My IDE is Netbeans 7.3.1, using Gradle plugin for Netabeans, using [JavaFX plugin](http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2013/05/18/javafx-gradle-plugin-0-dot-3-0-released/) for Gradle.

Simple JavaFX application:

i.lunin.autoposting.Main:

```
package i.lunin.autoposting;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World! Man!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Gradle file:

build.gradle:

```
apply from: "http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/0.3.0/javafx.plugin"
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

group = 'i.lunin.autoposting'
version = '0.0.0'

javafx {
    mainClass = 'i.lunin.autoposting.Main'
}
```

When I use `gradle run`, it runs perfectly inside my IDE; But I can't start it without IDE.

When I use `gradle :jfxDeploy` It says that the is finished.

After that, when I'm try to start the executable jar from:

"... TestJava\build\distributions"

It shows the following error: "Unable to find class: i.lunin.autoposting.Main"

Please help me make an executable jar under netbeans, gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. For me it turned out to be the build system.
If I build my app via gradle and javafx on a 32bit jvm, it resulted in the same error you had.
If I built it on a 64bit system everything went fine.
So I guess it's still a problem to deploy self contained 32bit java apps. I tested it with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to exist a newer plugin which looks very promissing:

From the repository README:

> Using javafx-gradle-plugin enhances your build-script with
>   javapackager-power. No more using Apache Ant-calls, because this
>   gradle-plugin wraps all calls and introduces workarounds and fixes for
>   not-yet-fixed JDK-bugs. This gradle-plugin is a convenient-wrapper for
>   the javapackger, so you have to visit the official documentation to
>   know about the requirements on each operating-system.
>
> Why does this gradle-plugin exist?
>
> In the need of some equivalent of the javafx-maven-plugin just for
>   gradle, this project was born. A lot of you might have used the
>   javafx-gradle-plugin from Danno Ferrin, but he decided to not continue
>   that project.

Check it out at https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin